# NoClassDefFoundError on android - a very wierd situation?

Tags: android, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I am facing with a wierd situation where the class is definitely on the classpath of my android app but I keep getting NoClassDefFoundError exceptions.

I have checked that the class indeed exists through this code snippet:

```
try{
  Field dexField = PathClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("mDexs");
  dexField.setAccessible(true);

  PathClassLoader classLoader =
   (PathClassLoader)Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  Log.d("OUT", "Class loader" + classLoader.getClass().getName());

  DexFile[] dexs = (DexFile[]) dexField.get(classLoader);

  Log.d("OUT", "Enumerating");
  for (DexFile dex : dexs) {
    Enumeration<String> entries = dex.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
     // (3) Each entry is a class name, like "foo.bar.MyClass"
     String entry = entries.nextElement();
     Log.d("OUT", "Entry: " + entry);
    }
  }
 }catch(Throwable e){
   Log.e("OUT", e.getMessage(), e);
 }
 // Here I reference to the problematic class
```

When running the app on a device the log does print the class name, and throws the NoClassDefFoundError error upon accessing to it.

I'm lost here.

Any advice? I'd be very grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand that, at least in canonical Java, "NoClassDefFoundError" does not mean that the named .class file could not be found in the classpath.  Rather, after it was located some problem prevented the class from being loaded.

Two common reasons for this are a naming problem (the class in the wrong location in the classpath structure, relative to its internally declared package name, or simply misnamed), or a problem loading some other class that's needed to perform validation of the named class.  Occasionally the problem is due to an exception in the static initializer of the class.

Comment: Just found out the reason. I have two projects one is a library project which is being referenced from the main project. Although the library project has all the needed jar files and compiles without errors, the jar files are not being exported into the apk file even if the eclipse is explicitly set to export all resources. So I had to include the jar files in the main app as well and include the jars in the classpath. I would think that logically all the dependent jars should be ported from the library app into the main app, but apparently this is not the case.